# Use variable from template.php in block

Tags: theming

I have a custom table in the Drupal DB, which I need to retrive and use on a few places on the site I'm creating. And I don't like to run soo much PHP in blocks, so I thought that I could get the table value I need, using PHP in template.php in the theme-dir and then just call the variable from a block, using PHP.

That didn't work.. Why and how should it be done?

template.php:

```
$sub_count = db_query("SELECT count FROM {sub_count}")->fetchField();
```

block:

```
<?php $sub_count; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a preprocess function.  Take a look at [template_preprocess_block()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--block--block.module/function/template_preprocess_block/7).  In your template.php you can use:

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['sub_count'] = db_query("SELECT count FROM {sub_count}")->fetchField();
}
```

and can print into the .tpl.php file as you did above.

A few good articles to learn more about preprocess functions are

- [About overriding themable output](http://drupal.org/node/173880)
- [Setting up variables for use in a template (preprocess and process functions)](http://drupal.org/node/223430)

As a basic overview of preprocess functions, from the second article:

> Preprocess functions only apply to theming hooks implemented as
>   templates. The main role of the preprocessor is to set up variables to
>   be placed within the template (.tpl.php) files. Plain theme functions
>   do not interact with preprocessors.
>
> Notes:
>
> - Preprocessors are also used for providing template suggestions.
> - In versions 5 and below, the function _phptemplate_variables served the
>     same purpose. It has been deprecated in 6.
> - Prior to Drupal 6.7, for your theme to have its preprocessors recognized, the template
>     associated with the hook had to exist inside the theme. When a default
>     template exists, copy it to your theme and clear the registry (or you
>     should really be upgrading to a later version of Drupal anyway for
>     security reasons, at which point you don't have to worry about this).

Comment: Thank you, but this means that I can't use a variable inside a block?